# Como copiar y pegar una tabla de excel en un datagridview vacio en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Quisiera saber si es posible copiar una sección de un archivo de excel y pegarlo directo en un datagridview, ya que normalmente solo te deja copiar y pegar por celda solamente , a continuacion muestro con imagenes el resultado que quisiera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es copiar por ejemplo la informacion anterior del excel y copiarlo para que quede algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el ejemplo anterior lo hice con otra forma de importar pero copiar y pegar seria considerablemente mas rapido, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho